# In KineticJS, on a canvas rotated using css3, the events don't seem to be working properly

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, kineticjs

I'm using Kineticjs for a rotating pie-chart widget. When I try to draw on a rotated canvas element (the parent node is rotated 60deg using CSS3), the events don't seem to be working properly. For example, the hover event on a 15 deg clockwise rotated canvas is 15 deg off. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please? I suspect that you will have to apply rotation inside KineticJS as well.

Comment: The actual code is a bit long but here's a jsfiddle of my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cf43Y/1/

Comment: This looks like an issue with KineticJS's stage. Check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/VGYas/ I tracked mousePosition on the stage and it looks like although the Canvas DOM element is rotated, the Stage Event Detection canvas is not. For example: the coordinates at the top left corner of the newly rotated green square is (0,100). But if the stage had rotated properly, the correct mousePos coordinates should be (0,200).

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Is there anyway to rotate the Stage Event Detection Canvas? (HitCanvas right?) Its not an element added to the dom I suppose?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. This question might be better suited for the KineticJS GitHub: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues or until Eric Rowell comes by here. As for the HitCanvas, I thought that it WAS rendered. In my app using KineticJS 4.5.0, I do see 2 canvases in my DOM. In your fiddle, and on all the examples with the html5canvastutorials.com tutorials section, I only see 1 canvas now. I also tried changing the KineticJS version on the tutorial examples to 4.5.0, but still only 1 canvas is in the DOM...

Comment: Sorry, I updated my fiddle it was a bit off (nothing new though just removed some styles). With a little more research: you can get the HitCanvas with http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getHitCanvas and also take a look at the Canvas Element API: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Canvas.html there is no rotate() function defined for it, but it might not be so hard to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to your question is not trivial---here’s why:**

Your DOM container is in transformed space.

Your Kinetic objects react as if they are in non-transformed space.

Your kinetic objects are mis-responding because the browser is feeding them transformed mouse positions.

**The simple fix:** Leave the DOM container untransformed and do all rotations inside KineticJS

**The difficult fix:** convert rotated DOM mousepoints into unrotated points for Kinetic to use.

Here's the difficult fix:

The default rotation-point of CSS transforms is 50%,50% (the middle of the element) so find the center of the Kinetic stage

```
var cx=stage.getWidth()/2;
var cy=stage.getHeight()/2;
```

Given a mouseX/mouseY in transformed space (DOM space),  you need to  find the untransformed point (KineticJS space)

```
var unrotatedPoint = unrotatedXY(cx,cy, mouseX,mouseY, cssDegreeRotation);
```

Here’s the function that does that calculation:

```
function unrotatedXY(cx,cy, mouseX,mouseY, cssDegreeRotation) {

    var dx=mouseX-cx;
    var dy=mouseY-cy;
    var r=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var cssRadianAngle = cssDegreeRotation * Math.PI/180;

    // calc the angle of the mouse position
    var rotatedAngle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

    // unrotate the mouse position by the css rotation
    var unrotatedAngle = rotatedAngle -= cssRadianAngle;

    // normalize the angle
    if(unrotatedAngle<0){ unrotatedAngle+=Math.PI*2; }

    // calc the unrotated XY
    unrotatedX = cx+ r * Math.cos(unrotatedAngle);
    unrotatedY = cy+ r * Math.sin(unrotatedAngle);

    return({x:unrotatedX,y:unrotatedY});
}
```

The mouseX/mouseY above are coming from the document, not KineticJS.

This means you must listen for mouse events on the document (or your container element), not in KineticJS itself.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function handleMouseMove(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

 // convert the DOM mousepoint to a Kinetic mousepoint
var unrotatedPoint = unrotatedXY(cx,cy, mouseX,mouseY, cssDegreeRotation);

// Now you can check for hovers, etc against your Kinetic nodes …

}
```

To tie back into KineticJS, you might use node.fire to trigger events using custom event objects containing your converted mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As markE suggested, there was no easy fix. The issue can be seen [here](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/521). It was closed recently.

The original error was apparently caused by jquery's event handling code. It works properly as of the latest version.